# Error when restarting postfix

Tags: postfix, centos5

When I have restarting the postfix server I am facing the below error ::

```
postfix-out/master[1714]: fatal: open lock file pid/master.pid: cannot create file exclusively: Permission denied
```

I having a centos server.

Comment: Are you running this as root?

Comment: How exactly are you restarting it? Is there still a `master` process running after you try this?

Comment: Yes I am running the service as a root.I am making an instance server but when I restart the service I am getting the error.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this command to fix permissions on postfix files and directories.

```
postfix set-permissions
```

The file that controls these permissions is located here:

```
/etc/postfix/postfix-files
```

There may have been a stale master.pid file or or existing postfix process running, to clear these you could have done:

```
service postfix stop
pkill -9 postfix
rm -f /var/spool/pid/master.pid
postfix set-permissions
service postfix start
```

Answer (score 1):

This file is created every time postfix starts.

In debian the file is created in /var/lib/postfix/master.lock, you have to looking for the directoyr of your postfix an check the permissions and the owners of it.

Comment: I have checked the permission and the permission are correct as below:: ls -ld /var/lib/postfix/master.lock
-rw-------. 1 postfix postfix 33 Feb  5 11:07 /var/lib/postfix/master.lock
Can you please tell me what to do next?

Comment: if postfix are not running and master.lock file exist you should delete it then postfix can create it when starts.